# Access to UITableViewController cells collection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I have a UITableViewController and need to gain access to the tableview's cells collection. The table view contains a list of user defined favorites represented by managed objects.

If the number of objects represented fits in one view, everything works. However, if the number of cells does not fit in the view, I get a runtime error when trying to build an array of cells.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++){
    [cells addObject:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]];
}
```

How can I get a full list of cells? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To put all cells into array is really bad idea, because off-screen cells can be re-used by UITableView. You should read this guide [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) and get some more knowledge about UITableView's. **You really should know how it works.**